# select rows in appengine database based on key ids

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following model:

```
class Notes(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    text =  db.StringProperty()
```

as we know app engine adds a `key` to each of the `Notes`. the `key` has `id` and `name`
how can i filter notes based on `ids` of the `key`.

i don't want to use the key rather the id, key looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Notes', id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `Key` for any query using the `Key` class's `from_path` factory, e.g.:

```
k = Key.from_path('User', 'Boris')
```

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_from_path